# TypeError: obj is undefined and refers to a line with $.each

Tags: javascript, ajax, object, datatable, typeerror

I am trying to add an item to database and reload it in my ajax `datatable`. However, every time I click the add button after filling down the form, I get `TypeError: obj is undefined` in the browser console and the item won't be added to the database nor the `datatable`. The error refers to the line with `$.each(res.errors, function(key,value)`. How to fix this? Or is there another way to do it.

Another scenario is I click the add button without filling down the form, so some styling classes will be added to warn the user that the form must be filled, and the code works.

I use Firefox and Laravel.

The error only shows up when I fill the form and click add.

```
$('#modal-btn-save').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault()

var form = $('#modal-body form'),
    url = form.attr('action'),
    method = $('input[name=_method]').val() == undefined ? 'POST' : 'PUT'

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: method,
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function(response){
        form.trigger('reset')
        $('#datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
    },
    error: function(xhr){
        var res = xhr.responseJSON;
        if ($.isEmptyObject(res) == false){
            $.each(res.errors, function(key,value){ 
                $('#' + key)
                    .closest('.form-group')
                    .addClass('has-error')
                    .append('<span class="help-block"><strong>' + value + '</strong></span>')
            })
        }
    }
})})
```

I expect the item would be added to the datatable just like in this tutorial and without the TypeError message in the console. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B2CeceGOVy8 I've tried to copy paste the code to see if I've missed a character, but nope, I still get the same error. Please help.

Comment: `res.errors` is undefined, so attempting to iterate the keys/values causes the exception

Comment: @r3wt So is it only defined when I don't fill the form? Because when I don't fill the form and I console logged it, res.errors has the expected values. Where does the action when I fill the form and click add in this case? It doesn't go to the error function but it doesn't go to success either. And why does it even access the $.each line if the error function seem to only check if the input is empty?

Comment: Now that I found what's wrong, this questions doesn't seem to matter anymore because I was focusing on the wrong problem. I found out the request gave 500 error, then it led me to know that I didnt add the csrf token function and set timestamp to false in its model to suit my table. Now everything works as expected.